# Is it possible to broadcast ARP from the command line?

Tags: windows, linux

Would be possible to invoke an ARP broadcast from the command line when running Windows and Linux? If so what would the commands be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **arp.exe** command is an external command accessed through the C:\Windows or C:\Winnt\System32 directory and is available in Microsoft operating systems.

```
ARP -s inet_addr eth_adr [if_addr]
ARP -d inet_addr [if_addr]
ARP -a [inet_addr] [-N if_addr]
```

Switches are [here](http://www.computerhope.com/arphlp.htm).

On linux the command is just **arp**

```
arp [-vn] [-H type] [-i if] -a [hostname]
arp [-v] [-i if] -d hostname [pub]
arp [-v] [-H type] [-i if] -s hostname hw_addr [temp]
arp [-v] [-H type] [-i if] -s hostname hw_addr [netmask nm] pub
arp [-v] [-H type] [-i if] -Ds hostname ifa [netmask nm] pub
arp [-vnD] [-H type] [-i if] -f [filename]
```

Switches are [here](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/arp.htm).

Comment: Ooh. T'anks, Nifle!